# How to add current time in rdl?

Tags: rdl

How to add Current Time in Rdl report SSRS.

Please any one help me...
 I am using Date for

```
   =DateAdd("m", -1, Now)
```

but for Time only?

Comment: How do I change the date in Spanish in =now()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying include the print time and date you can also use the global variable

```
=Globals.ExecutionTime
```

Comment: How do I change the date in Spanish

Answer (score 0):

Try this !

```
 =Now()

 =DATEADD("m", -1, now())
```

Comment: How do I change the date in Spanish. pls